# How do I use the "right-to-left override" in Safari for Mac?

Tags: macos, safari, unicode

I'd like to use the "right-to-left override" (unicode character 202E) in Safari. How do I make it work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If all you want is to make it work in Safari:

```
This is left to right, &#8238;but this is right to left,<br />
and then this is back to left to right again.
```

results in:

> This is left to right, ‮but this is right to left,
>       and then this is back to left to right again.

The important bit is the **&#8238;**—everything after that will be reversed.

Note: this assumes that the web page is using UTF-8 (and if it isn't, it should be).

Comment: Yeah, but it won't work in SE chat and comments.

Comment: @Nyuszika do you really want to type inverted here? ;)

Comment: ‮Yeah, probably. :)

Comment: How would I make it work elsewhere?

Comment: @Moshe - where else do you want it? It should work in other browsers as well, and pretty much anywhere that can handle that type of HTML entity. FWIW, there's no real difference between `document.getElementById("bkwd").innerHTML="\u202e backwards";` and 
`document.getElementById("bkwd").innerHTML="&#8238; backwards";`—it's just that the latter can also be typed directly into the text of an HTML page.

Answer (score 7):

Open up the Web Inspector with <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> and type in this:

```
copy('\u202e');
```

If this won't throw an error, the right-to-left override is copied to your clipboard. You can try it even in the console, just press <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> and then type some text.

This works cross-platform (just be sure to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> in Windows), in all WebKit browsers, **but only inside the console**.

---

**Update:** I've just installed Safari 5 on Win7 x64, and it seems that the character is copied to the clipboard, but Safari can't handle it. The HTML entity that Dori suggested will work in any HTML document. There, it will work in questions and answers, but not in chat and comments.

Comment: Don't know why... This didn't work.

Comment: Safari won't let me type it in chat. I wonderif it would work inasking a question?

Comment: I've already said that the HTML entity won't work in chat and comments. Yes, it works in questions and answers.

Comment: The strange thing is that it renders the backwards chat and comments.

Comment: You need to copy that character from somewhere else. I'm using Chrome, and what I've said works fine for me.